# Reinstalling wordpress from database breaks the site

Tags: database, installation

For a relaunched website I need to move the old wordpress site to an /archive subfolder. I reinstalled wordpress into that folder and the default blank wordpress worked fine.

Then I changed the database info in the wp-config.php to match the existing database and copied the old theme folder.

Now when I open up the page it shows the posts but none of the permalinks or the css works anymore and when I try to enter the admin panel it also gives me an error when browsing to /archive/wp-admin. I don’t really understand what the database has to do with that and how it can be fixed.

I also tried changing the db_version number in the database to the one thats saved inside /wp-includes/version.php but it didn’t help either.

If I refresh the admin panel when I update the wp-config to the correct db info I get the following error message:

> No web page was found for the web address:
> https://www.domain.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Farchive%2Fwp-admin%2F

The global php version on the server is 7.4 and the MySQL database is on version 5.6 so this should not be an issue.

Thank you very much!

Comment: did you migrate the old databases URL to the new URL? If so, what method did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it:
Toms comment made me check how I could migrate the database URL without accessing the admin panel. Turns out it’s really easy. Go to phpMyAdmin and into your wp database. Go into the wp_options table and the first row should be the site url. Change it to the correct site (and subfolder). From then I could log into the admin panel and change permalinks and so on.

Thank you Tom!